# Full screen, centered image in ionic modal

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic V1 and have a simple modal that shows an image that I want to have maximum (fullscreen) dimension so that it's centered vertically and horizontally, with full screen on the appropriate dimension (width or height) depending on the device orientation (portrait or landscape).

When viewing an image that is 1024px W x 768px H in portrait mode, the image is sized as though the  device is in landscape mode, and the sides are cropped.

But rotating the device to landscape mode causes a perfect full screen image.

```
<ion-content>
   <div id="photo-fullscreen" ng-click="photoModalClose()" style="width:100%;height:100%;background:url({{fullscreenPhoto}}) center center no-repeat;">
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

How do I set this CSS so the image is centered and the dimensions match the device orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="flex-content">
    <img id="photo-fullscreen" ng-src="{{fullscreenPhoto}}">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; /* Center in main axis */
  align-items: center; /* Center in cross axis */
}
#photo-fullscreen {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%
}
```